# CoreBluetooth monitoring 100 beacons with same UUID with unique enters

Tags: ios, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I use `CoreLocation` to monitor iBeacons. The problem is that if I for example 100 beacons with same UUID clustered I get only one `didEnterRegion`, not 100.

Can I fix it by coding my own implementation with `CoreBluetooth` ?

`CoreLocation` doesn't need any capabilities on (background modes) to monitor while the app is in background. Does `CoreBluetooth` need it ? Does apple let apps with these capabilities to the store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can get `CoreBluetooth` callbacks when beacons are in the vicinity, Apple blocks the ability to read any beacon data using `CoreBluetooth`.  So this is not a solution.  See details here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

An alternative solution is to use `CoreLocation` to combine region monitoring with ranging.  You then put your code in the `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:`
ranging callback (not the monitoring callbacks).  The ranging callback provides an array of all beacons in that region that are visible at the current time.  In your case, if 100 beacons were visible at the same time, this callback would contain an array of 100 beacons allowing you to see the identifiers of each.

Comment: Wow... It's like Apple makes a hobby of making our lives harder. Like the 20 max beacons thing in region monitoring. It renders beacons almost useles... Thanks!